# CFG for L={ a^n b^m : n <= m+3 , n,m>=0}

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I want to find Context Free Grammar for L={ a^n b^m : n <= m+3 , n,m>=0}

What I have so far

```
S -> AAAB
A -> a | ε
B -> aBb | Bb | ε
```

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this CFG should work properly
But the CFG below is more readable :

```
S -> aSb | A | B
A -> a | aa | aaa | ε
B -> bB | ε
```